# Sed escaping special chars

Tags: regex, sed

To make the sed to work with an alternation construction we must espace special chars like `(` or `|`:

```
sed -n "/\(abc\|def\)/p"
```

Simple

```
sed -n "/(abc|def)/p"
```

doesn't work.

My question is: why does sed behaves contrariwise to the "normal" regex where we escape special chars to give them literal meaning?

Comment: Use POSIX ERE if you do not like BRE and your sed supports it. `sed -En "/(abc|def)/p"`

Comment: If by "normal" regex you mean Basic Regular Expressions (BRE): the POSIX definition of them does not include alternation at all, and grouping requires escaping, `\(...\)`, as in your first example. GNU (and GNU sed) allows alternation as an extension to BRE, and requires it to be escaped `\|` – that's your first example. Your second example uses Extended Regular Expressions (ERE), where `()` don't have to be escaped, and alternation is just `|`. GNU and some other seds support ERE (but not POSIX sed), but require a flag like `-E` or `-r` to indicate that you're using them.

Comment: A small point. In the example you posted, there are only two alternatives in the regexp provided and nothing either side, so the grouping is unnecessary and can be written `sed -n 's/abc\|def/p' file`

Answer (score 1):

What you call "normal" is a feature invented by Perl.

All traditional regex engines (e.g. the ones used by grep, sed, emacs, awk) have some special characters that match literally when escaped and normal characters that get a special meaning when escaped. My best guess for why this happened is evolution: Maybe the first implementation of regexes only supported `[`, `]`, and `*`, and everything else was matched literally. To introduce new features while keeping compatibility, the escaped syntax (`\(`, `\)`, etc.) was invented.

Later on, other tools just copied the existing syntax.

As far as I know, Perl was the first language to make regex syntax more, well, regular:

- All alphanumeric characters match themselves.
- Escaping an alphanumeric character may have a special meaning (e.g. `\n`, `\1`, `\z`).
- Punctuation characters may have a special meaning (e.g. `(`, `+`, `?`).
- Escaping a non-alphanumeric character always makes it match literally, even if it wasn't special in the first place (e.g. `\:`, `\"`).

All "modern" regex engines (e.g. the ones used in JavaScript or .NET) copied Perl's behavior.